# How do I add a fragment to a ViewFlipper, programmatically, in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewflipper

I have one listview, when i click on listView Item the fragment load details of that item.I want to add that fragment to viewFlipper. when i slide that fragment i should able to see the details of next item.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.